# Pass json object to a second PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this javascript function that submits the object to another page:

```js
function submitForm(){
  var user = createUser();
  $.ajax({url: 'run.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: user,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      alert("success");
      console.log(data);
    },error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {alert("ERROR:" + xhr.responseText+" - "+thrownError);}
  });
    }
```

I also have an "index.php" page, that has a button that calls the "submitForm()" function:

```html
<body>
  ... a bunch of code
  <form>
   <input id="submit" type="submit" class="submit" value="submit" onclick="submitForm()">
  </form
</body>
```

So, when I click the "submit" button in the "index.php" page, the user is redirected to another page (run.php) in which the json object is echoed.

```html
<?php
  echo json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

I am going mad trying to solve this. I read a hundred of tutorials and questions here but none solved my problem.

Comment: If you set the `action` attribute of the `form` to the `index.php` page then you don't need any JS at all.

Comment: But the form is just for organization sake. What interests me is to pass this object, created by the function, to the second php page.

Comment: Add a hidden form field, populate it with the JSON string you got before you send the form … and then just read and decode the value on the next page.

Comment: What object? Your JS code shows nothing. If you want to send the data without refreshing the page then you can certainly use AJAX. I would suggest doing some research on the matter.

Comment: I'll try, @04FS . But Is the code for "run.php" right? Cheers.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, the object is in the "submitForm()" function. There I created a "user" variable that I want to send to the run.php page.

Comment: What is the issue? You appear to be expecting someone to write the code for you which is not what SO does. If you have an issue with the logic you have written please add it to the question, along with a description of your problem.

Comment: I'm not. I'm just expecting some light for the communication between the pages. I wrote the code for the ajax function, but I'm not sure if it's right, so I omitted. But I'll edit my question and add it anyway.

Comment: _“But Is the code for "run.php" right?”_ - if you want to encode everything that was received in $_POST _as_ JSON and output it at this point, then it would be. But if you actually want to _send_ a JSON string in the first place, it probably makes rather little sense to encode that as JSON again at this point. (Start by using `var_dump($_POST);` if you are not sure what data in what exact structure you are receiving in the first place.)

Comment: Thanks, @04FS. I'll also try this.

Answer (score 0):

Just add action attribute to the form tag and remove the javascript:

```
<body>
  ... a bunch of code
  <form action="run.php">
   <input id="submit" type="submit" class="submit" value="submit"/>
  </form
</body>
```

Comment: The thing is: the form is just for organization sake. The use of javascript is compulsory because of the nature of rest of the code. The "createUser()" function does many calculations, on the client-side, that are not in the "form" format.

Comment: Ahh I can see now that you're submitting the form via ajax call. So the problem is when you do that you simply send a request to run.php script and that causes the run.php script to run and return results but it will not redirect and show you the output in the browser. It will simply pass form data into that script and run it "outside of browser". So the quickest solution is to actually use action instead of ajax call and then echoing to post data on run.php page should work. You can still use the javascript for preprocessing and then do a form.submit() as a last step